# Battery level drops then is restored in seconds

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

Please read all the way to the end, this is not your typical "bad battery" problem. :)

I have a brand new Lenovo 700-15ISK laptop that seems to have a battery problem. This is the third laptop of the same model I have that has this. I have returned the other two for the exact same issue. A first and second time may just be bad luck, but now that I have the same problem a third time, I am starting to think it may be something that I am doing wrong...

This issue is this. While on battery power, at irregular intervals (sometimes once a day, sometimes 5 times an hour), the battery level indicator drops from the current level to a sudden critically low battery level of 6% or lower. Sometimes this prompts a warning telling me that I should hook up the charger, the next time, it does not. Then as if magic, a second later it reverts to its old level. I've seen this happen from anywhere between a full charge to 20% left.

The second one I owned has been with Lenovo on and off over a period of 4 months and I kept getting it back with them saying the laptop is operating "within acceptable parameters". This bothers me majorly because in this brief state of critically low power levels, it disconnects my external monitors, dims my screen and does all other things a laptop does when going into power saving mode. Not great.

I am running the original OS, Windows 10, right off the original hardware. I have all BIOS and driver updates installed and have tried restoring Windows a couple times.

I have drained and fully charged the battery a few times to no avail. It seems to be functioning fine and the estimated time is nearly always spot-on unless I drastically change the load on the machine.

All of the above to no avail on any of the laptops I have had from Lenovo.

*Any* lead would be greatly appreciated as I have been unable to find any sort of similar case on the internet despite having looked everywhere. The fact that this is the third time however, leads me to believe that this is more than just the bad luck of getting a bad apple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the battery level indicator on this laptop is just bogus.
Most battery indicators are very imprecise, but yours may just be more erratic
than most.

I think that you should at least try to reset the battery gauge using
Energy Management, as described in the HP support page of
[How to perform battery gauge reset using Energy Management](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/solutions/ht069480).
Or alternatively see
[How to calibrate the battery using OneKey Optimizer](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/solutions/ht500710).

Comment: Unfortunately, this model does not support these utilities and the Lenovo software on this laptop now does not feature this functionality. I checked with Lenovo on this, it should be "self-regulatory" according to them.

Comment: The only way to find out how precise is the gauge, is to continue until the laptop shuts down. I once had a laptop that shut itself down when the indication was 20%.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have drained and fully charged the battery a few times to no avail. It seems to be functioning fine and the estimated time is nearly always spot-on unless I drastically change the load on the machine.

Comment: I can't think of anything else you can do except two : (1) Accept the situation as-is and ignore these spurious warnings, (2) Ask to be reimbursed (if possible) and get another laptop model. If you know of a good computer-repair shop you could ask them if they know more about the problem. Or maybe someone else could come up here with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have found more users who have been struggling with this issue for anywhere between days to 4 months. I have therefore decided to go for reimbursement as this is clearly a known problem that has been known since the product launch and has been unresolved since. Despite multiple attempts through driver and BIOS updates. Lost faith in Lenovo finding a solution anytime soon as it doesn't seem to be high up on their list of priorities. It always seemed like a hardware problem to me and I now have more user claims to back that up. (I'm not crazy! :D)

---

Anyone stumbling on this, for reference:

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-100-305-500-Edge/Ideapad-700-15ISK-false-low-battery-warnings/m-p/3515949
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-100-305-500-Edge/Ideapad-700-15ISK-battery-icon-problem/m-p/3543968